# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo .. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, instantiation, android-volley

I'm trying to run a simple app using volley and a custom header, it builds with no error, I'm running it directly in my smartphone, but when the app start I get the following log:

```
06-24 16:35:35.653    1380-1380/com.rep E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rep, PID: 1380
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rep/com.rep.app.principal.InicioActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:230)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:43)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
            at com.representemais.app.principal.InicioActivity.<init>(InicioActivity.java:86)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

that's the InicioActivity:

```
package com.rep.app.principal;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.rep.R;


import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;


public class InicioActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        AutenticacaoLocalTask mAutenticacaoLocalTask = new AutenticacaoLocalTask();
        mAutenticacaoLocalTask.execute((Void) null);

    }
    private TextView txtDisplay;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    public class AutenticacaoLocalTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


            try {




                txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

                String url = "http://192.168.1.15/rep-api/api/clients";







                 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        url, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                txtDisplay.setText("Response => "+response.toString());
                                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());


                    }
                })



                {

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        headers.put("X-API-TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkD0bDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");

                        return headers;
                    }



                };
                queue.add(jsonObjReq);


                return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RM", e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

        }
    }


}
```

and the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rep"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".app.principal.InicioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".app.login.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".app.principal.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".app.cliente.ClienteDetalheActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".app.login.LoginTelaBloqueada"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your `RequestQueue`, using `Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`, in `onCreate()` after the `super.onCreate()` call. You are trying to use your `Activity` from an initializer, which frequently causes problems like this.

---

Step #1: Replace:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

with:

```
RequestQueue queue = null;
```

Step #2: Change your `onCreate()` to be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    AutenticacaoLocalTask mAutenticacaoLocalTask = new AutenticacaoLocalTask();
    mAutenticacaoLocalTask.execute((Void) null);

}
```

Comment: but now the queue is never used

Comment: @WARpoluido: If you are not using it, get rid of it.

Comment: but I'm using it on this line : "queue.add(jsonObjReq);"

Comment: @WARpoluido: First, you say it is never used. Then, you say that you are using it. You are going to need to determine, for yourself, which of your two comments is correct. Regardless of whether you are or are not using it, do not call `newRequestQueue()` until after `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the OP need to call the `newRequestQueue()` to start a specific function. And calling it After `super.onCreate()` is disabling the call "queue it's never being used"...

Comment: @MichelAyres: "I think the OP need to call the newRequestQueue() to start a specific function" -- hopefully not, since it presently is called in an initializer. That, of course, is the problem -- you cannot safely refer to an `Activity` from an initializer.

Comment: @CommonsWare +Michel is right, this is my problem. I'm kinda lost on how should I refer to an activity if not in the `initializer`